# How to insert namespace to VSCode in linux (C++)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, namespaces

I have to include 3rd party package that has defined a namespace gxns (C++ ubuntu 18.04). There is no issue to use makefile on ubuntu platform by using

-I/usr/include/gx   #inlcude file for the 3rd party pacakge

-L/usr/lib/gx -lgx_lib  #  link to the library associated with 3rd party package

file /usr/include/gx/gxsd.h defines the namespace gxns as follows:

```cpp
namespace gxns {
 ....
};
```

in my code main.cpp

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "gxsd.h"
...
using namespace std;

using namespace gxns;
```

Now I want to port it to vscode platform. However there is a compiling error even after taking the following steps:

in "c_cpp_properties.json",  I added the following

```json
"configuration": [
    {
    "name":"Linux",
    "includePath": {

       .....
        "/usr/include/gx/**",
   ....

     }
  }
]

tasks.json 

    {
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-I/home/dallas/GIT/dallas_tx/common/include",
                "-I/usr/include/gx",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

When I compile, error shows up - "gxns is not a namespace". any suggestions or tips to resolve the compilation issue?

Similarly, how to link the library lib_gx in vscode?

Compiling error: can not recognize a namespace provided by 3rd party

Comment: Please fix the formatting, this is too hard to read.

Comment: ***When I compile, error shows up - "gxns is not a namespace".*** Does not look like an error caused by a bad configuration of a build task. It's more likely a missing include in your c++ code or possibly a circular header loop.

Comment: `"-I/usr/include/",` your compiler should already include this

Comment: Weren't all these fancy GUI IDEs and editors, like VSCode, with their pretty dialogs and buttons, supposed to make things easier, to avoid all these yucky `Makefile`s and shell commands? You mean that I must concoct some magic incantation in the form of a convoluted JSON configuration file, to get basic functionality right? That's a darn shame, isn't it? After reading `make`s man page, as lengthy as it is, with plenty of examples, it's always pretty straightofrward for me to simply push `F5` in emacs, and get everything built.

Comment: What task are you running - can you display the full/complete task. Is it trying to run `make` or some other command? - you have only really shown the arguments to a command...

Comment: vscode is not a platform. It is a text editor, and not a very easy one to use. It is supposed to be beginner-friendly but it is not. Why use it?

Comment: I updated the tasks.json . The reason I explore vscode is because of its advertised debug features : step into,  step over...

Comment: "gxsd.h"   is the headfile to have the namespace gxns. It is already included in the main.cpp. I do not think it is "include" issue, rather it is somewhere in the configuration/setting on vscode. . The code was ok to run on the command line with classical approach-makefile

Answer (score 0):

> I updated the tasks.json . The reason I explore vscode is because of its advertised debug features : step into, step over..

vscode does not provide this - GDB (or similar) will provide this for you. However you can integrate the usage of GDB into vscode pretty easily.

Your task appears to be compiling a single file like:

```bash
g++ -I/home/dallas/GIT/dallas_tx/common/include -I/usr/include/gx SOMEFILE.cpp -o SOMEDIR/SOMEFILE
```

omitting the some options that don't really matter. You don't appear to have the options: `-L/usr/lib/gx -lgx_lib` included in there. If you add those it will probably work - i.e. something like:

```json
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-I/home/dallas/GIT/dallas_tx/common/include",
                "-I/usr/include/gx",
                "-L/usr/lib/gx",
                "-lgx_lib",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
```

However - if there is a makefile already there why not just use that and change your task? - something like:

```json
            "command": "make",
            "args": [],
```

assuming the makefile is at the top level. Its far easier to edit a makefile and have your build task just call that (IMO).